# How to capture Data Loader error when called from Shell script via SSIS package?

Tags: data-loader, java, bulk-api, sqlserver, commandline

**Salesforce Gurus:**
Thank you in advance for any insights you may have.

For years now I have been extracting data from a custom Salesforce object named Branches__c using the following method...

```
Public Sub Main()

    Dim ExtractBranches As String           'the Branches extract run file

    ExtractBranches = "Y:\importFiles\SF\Replication\ApexDataLoader\sfc.Branches__c\config\run.cmd"

    Shell(ExtractBranches, AppWinStyle.NormalFocus, True)

End Sub
```

This script is called from an SSIS package which is scheduled to run on a daily basis using a SQL Server Agent job.

Yesterday, after upgrading to the current version of the Data Loader and the current version of Java, the extract is no longer being created when called by the SQL Server Agent job. However the extract is created as before if I open the SSIS package in Visual Studio and run it manually.

What I have tried so far is this...

I am using the Bulk API for this extract. I monitor the progress via the "Monitor Bulk Data Load Jobs" screen. I can see that the bulk job is not being sent to the cloud when called from the SQL Server Agent job because no Job ID is ever created.

I have ruled out the run.cmd file and the config.properties file as being part of the issue. This is the contents of run.cmd file...

```
C:
cd \"Program Files (x86)"\salesforce.com\"Data Loader"\bin\
process.bat Y:\importFiles\SF\Replication\ApexDataLoader\sfc.Branches__c\config
```

I can run the run.cmd file outside of SQL Server all together just by clicking on it. When I do, the extract is created as expected.

So far I have not found a way to capture the error that is causing the extract to not be created via the SQL Server Agent job route.

For your reference, here are some more details about the environment I am working in...

Data Loader upgrade:
Upgraded from Apex Data Loader 22 to dataloader-37.0.0

Java:
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_131
C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_131

JAVA_HOME
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_131

Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise Service Pack 1

Microsoft Visual Studio 2010
Version 10.0.40219.1 SP1Rel
Microsoft .NET Framework
Version 4.6.01590 SP1Rel

SQL Server Integration Services
Microsoft SQL Server Integration Services Designer
Version 11.0.2100.60

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much hand wringing, I realized that after upgrading to the current version of Java, I had not yet restarted the server. I restarted the server and the issue is now resolved.